# Tools > Android menu doesn't exist in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-virtual-device

From the docs:

> To run the AVD Manager, do one of the following:
>
> - In Android Studio, select **Tools > Android > AVD Manager**.
> - Click **AVD Manager** in the toolbar.

Neither of these things exist.

I went into the settings and found the AVD Manager menu item that isn't displayed, and assigned it a keyboard shortcut, but it didn't do anything.

Other sources on the web mention running `android avd` to start the AVD Manager, but this was deprecated and removed.

```
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command "avd"
```

How do I open the AVD Manager?

Comment: "Neither of these things exist" -- do you have an Android project open, or is your project a pure Java JAR project? What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.2, and I tried to configure it as an Android project, but it didn't seem to help. Currently I have the Project SDK set to "Android 6.0 Google APIs"

Comment: Using the new-project wizard, create a new Android project, in some scrap location (e.g., `/tmp` on macOS or Linux). You should see the AVD items in the locations that you describe in your question. If you do, then your original project is not being recognized as an Android project. If you do not see them, then your Android Studio installation is seriously messed up.

Comment: If I create a new project, it works. What qualifies a project as an Android project?

Comment: Frankly, through the new-project wizard, I don't know how to make a non-Android project. The only times that I have gotten into that state were when I tried importing an existing project and encountered some sort of problem (either operator error or project configuration issues).

Comment: Yes it seems the project wizard is only for Android projects, which makes sense. But how would I make an existing imported project into an Android project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The React Native CLI creates an Android project in the `android` directory.

In Android Studio, you can import (or open) this folder as a project, rather than the outer directory, and the **Tools > Android** option should appear. (It might take a few seconds for some reason.)

Comment: This sounds like what I need. However, you aren't providing any details in order to do this. Can you please provide the Steps To Reproduce your solution? I've checked the Android folder in both of my Program Files folders and there isn't a project to open.

Comment: @BermudaLamb The `android` folder should be in a directory in your project (repo) folder. Something like `build/android/`.

Answer (score 11):

Just follow the prompts in the android terminal window.

I was able to fix this by trying to build the gradle and when that failed, it prompted me with "install missing platforms and sync project". This fixed the issue. It took about 5 minutes to resolve the gradle dependencies.

Note: This was trying to run an ionic application from the raw ionic generated android code. It is not initially recognized as an android project or application until you do those steps.

Until that all finished, tools>Android>menu was not available.

Answer (score 8):

Just create a new project, then you will get a gradle sync message like this:

[image: Build tools]

Then click the link to install Build Tools.

And that's all

Comment: unbelieveable that it is work! thank you for you and shame on you android studio ....

Answer (score 3):

> But how would I make an existing imported project into an Android project?

Technically, AFAIK, it's the existence of `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` or `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in the appropriate `build.gradle` file, along with the requisite setup for that in the appropriate `build.gradle` file. If you look at the Android project that you just created, you will see one `build.gradle` file in the project root directory and another in `app/`. The top-level `build.gradle` file configures where to obtain plugins (via the `buildscript` closure, where "closure" is "things in `{}`"). The `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` statement in the module's `build.gradle` file says "this module creates an Android app", while `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` says "this module creates an Android library". My assumption is that you are missing part or all of this.

The simplest solution, IMHO, would be to create a new project, then drag-and-drop the Java code and other relevant bits from the somewhat-broken project into the new one. If you drag-and-drop between two Android Studio windows, it's fairly smart, and it also honors the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-for-copy-vs.-move pattern (at least on Windows/Linux). This way, you are starting with a properly-configured Android project and merely adding in the code and stuff that you want it to have.

Alternatively, you can look at the new project and try to retrofit your existing project (e.g., modifying the `build.gradle` file(s)). An experienced developer can do this with mild difficulty; it's not the sort of thing that I would recommend to newcomers to Android.

Comment: The project had the proper gradle files, but Android Studio wasn't finding them. I realized this is because I'm using React Native and the Android project is in the `android` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Bump into this problem when installing Android Studio on a new machine. In my case the problem was that **Intel Virtualization was not enable on BIOS**.

Android Studio installed successfully but the menu option Tools->AVD Manager was not available. The problem was identified only when i try to reinstall manually [Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager - Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm)

The following steps were done, not all should be required for everyone:

```
1) Enable Intel Virtualization on computer BIOS
2) Reinstall Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager - Intel HAXM
3) Clone the project again from git
4) Synchronize gradle. Take long minutes to download all packages again.
5) Rebuild project
```

Only after this steps the menu Tools->AVD Manager appear. The run option for module App also become available at this time. Before that run module was an empty box.

Note: My Android Studio Version was 3.2

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem.

Check you don't have any errors on the bottom of android studio. I got one with sdk build. If you got the same click on the link in error log.

Next go to file -> settings -> Appearance&Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars. 
Roll up Main menu -> Tools. 
Choose Android. 
Click on 'Applay' button and 'OK'. 
Wait for a while (gradel progressbar on the bottom).

I hope that I solve your problem.

Comment: This is incomplete. What do you do after clicking on Android? There are no changes to apply.