# Android Studio doesn't show the Android Tab in the Tools dropdown menu

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

I am trying to run a project created by a colleague, so he zipped up the file and I downloaded it on my computer. I already viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293791/tools-android-menu-doesnt-exist-in-android-studio) link about the issue, however the reported solutions workn't for me. Here is a screenshot regarding my settings for SDK Tools, SDK Platforms and the dropdown menu in question. I have tried turning it on and off again.
[image]

Comment: what you want to do with android tab ?.

Comment: I want to configure ADK settings and set up an emulator

Comment: JasperMW please check my answer for how to set configurations and emulator from android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now **android studio** doesn't support the **android tab** anymore. You will have to set your requirements from **project settings** and set emulator using **AVD manager**. Below attached image will help you navigate through those steps:

[image]

Comment: Glad i could be of help. Happy coding 