# Don't show "android" option on Project Structure in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android development, last day i was doing a project but when i realize that project i don't need, then i just going to project path and **delete the project file from hard drive**. but after deleting the project, i am trying to create a new project but there is something shows that i didn't see before. and if i import a project from my computer, that time Project Structure don't show **"android"** option, and all projects show errors! even the Project Structure seems new for me. even i did uninstall my android studio and download new file and installed but it still seem like before!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tools > Android menu doesn't exist in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293791/tools-android-menu-doesnt-exist-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing **Android** menu, meaning your project is not recognised as an Android project. Try to open / import your project by **selecting the folder that contains** `.iml`, `settings.gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradle.properties`, etc.